# Find a local maximum value of probability function$~P_{\text{B}}(x)~$using natural logarithm function.

Tags: probability, derivatives, logarithms, maxima-minima, binomial-distribution

I've painted my most interest part of this post, with red color. Please scroll down to see it.

$$P_{\text{B}}(x):=\binom{n}{x}p^x q^{n-x}\tag{1}$$

$$
\begin{cases}
 p+q=1\\
x\in\left\{0,1,2,~. . . ~,n\right\}\\
1\ll n,x\in\mathbb{N}
\end{cases}\tag{2}
$$

$$g(x):=\ln\left(P_{\text{B}}(x)\right)\tag{3}$$

$$=\ln\left(\binom{n}{x}p^xq^{n-x}\right)\tag{4}$$

$$=\ln\left(\frac{n!}{\left(n-x\right)!x!}p^x\left(1-p\right)^{n-x}\right)\tag{5}$$

$$=\ln\left(\frac{n!}{\left(n-x\right)!x!}\right)+\ln\left(p^{x}\left(1-p\right)^{n-x}\right)\tag{6}$$

$$=\ln\left(n!\right)-\ln\left(\left(n-x\right)!x!\right)+\ln\left(p^{x}\right)+\ln\left(\left(1-p\right)^{n-x}\right)\tag{7}$$

$$=\ln\left(n!\right)-\left(\ln\left(\left(n-x\right)!\right)+\ln\left(x!\right)\right)+x\ln\left(p\right)+\left(n-x\right)\ln\left(1-p\right)\tag{8}$$

$$=\ln\left(n!\right)-\ln\left(\left(n-x\right)!\right)-\ln\left(x!\right)+\ln\left(p\right)x+\ln\left(1-p\right)\left(n-x\right)\tag{9}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}g(x)\tag{10}$$

$$=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\left(\ln\left(n!\right)-\ln\left(\left(n-x\right)!\right)-\ln\left(x!\right)+\ln\left(p\right)x+\ln\left(1-p\right)\left(n-x\right)\right)\tag{11}$$

$$=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\ln\left(\left(n-x\right)!\right)-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\ln\left(x!\right)+\ln\left(p\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}x+\ln\left(1-p\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\left(n-x\right)\tag{12}$$

$$=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\ln\left(\left(n-x\right)!\right)-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\ln\left(x!\right)+\ln\left(p\right)-\ln\left(1-p\right)\tag{13}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\ln\left(x!\right)\approx\ln\left(x\right)~~\leftarrow~~\text{this apporximation is to be used}\tag{14}$$

[The derivation of it can be seen here(functionality of target="_blank"has not been implemented so open it in new tab please)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4398586/subproblem-of-transformation-to-standard-normal-distribution-from-binomial-distr)

About the first term of eqn13,

$$u:=n-x\tag{15}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\left(\ln\left(\left(n-x\right)!\right)\right)\tag{16}$$

$$=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\ln\left(u!\right)\tag{17}$$

$$=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{du}}\ln\left(u!\right)\frac{\mathrm{du}}{\mathrm{dx}}\tag{18}$$

$$\approx\ln\left(u\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\left(n-x\right)\tag{19}$$

$$=-\ln\left(n-x\right)\tag{20}$$

$$\therefore~~\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}g(x)\approx\ln\left(n-x\right)-\ln\left(x\right)+\ln\left(p\right)-\ln\left(1-p\right)\tag{21}$$

$$=\ln\left(\frac{n-x}{x}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)\tag{22}$$

$$=\ln\left(\frac{\left(n-x\right)}{x}\cdot\frac{p}{1-p}\right)\tag{23}$$

$$x~~\text{is now assumed as continuous variable}\tag{24}$$

$$\text{We will find value(s)of}~~x~~\text{such that}~~\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}g(x)=0\tag{25}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}g(x)=\ln\left(\frac{p\left(n-x\right)}{x\left(1-p\right)}\right)\tag{26}$$

$$\therefore~~\frac{p\left(n-x\right)}{x\left(1-p\right)}=1\tag{27}$$

$$p\left(n-x\right)=x\left(1-p\right)\tag{28}$$

$$np-px=x-xp\tag{29}$$

$$\therefore~~x=np\tag{30}$$

$$\mu_{}:=np\tag{31}$$

Currently I can't get the following claim.

$$\color{red}{P_{\text{B}}(x)~~\text{takes a local maximum value where}~x=np~~\text{is held}}\tag{32}$$

I've enumerated my thoughts for it as follows.

$~P_{\text{B}}(x)~$draws a graph which is resemble with following, as number of iterations$~(=n)~$is large.

This means that local extremum value of$~P_{\text{B}}(x)~$can be immediately determined as local maximum value.

[image]

Cited it from [here](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2021/11/08/normal-approximation-binomial.html)

$$g(x)=\ln\left(P_{\text{B}}(x)\right)\tag{33}$$

About above,$~g(x)~$returns a value of natural log function though argument for it is not linear as same as$~x~$for instance. $~P_{\text{B}}(x)~$can vary a slope itself depends on range where$~x~$belongs.

Since natural log function is a monotonic increasing function, the following claims are true.
$$
\begin{cases}
 P_{\text{B}}(x)~~\text{increases}~~\Leftrightarrow~~g(x)~~\text{increases}\\ 
 P_{\text{B}}(x)~~\text{decreases}~~\Leftrightarrow~~g(x)~~\text{decreases}\\
\end{cases}\tag{34}
$$

And still I can't get line32.

Comment: I got a little progress about it . I will post it later.

Answer (score 1):

$$P= \binom{n}{x}\, p^x\,q^{n-x}=\frac{\Gamma (n+1) }{\Gamma (x+1)\, \Gamma (n-x+1)}p^x\, q^{n-x}$$ Using logarithmic differentiation and replacing the digamma function by generalized harmonic numbers
$$\frac 1 P \frac{dP}{dx}=H_{n-x}-H_x+\log (p)-\log (q)$$

Using the approximation
$$H_p \simeq \gamma +\log(p)+O\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)$$ then
$$x=\frac{n p}{p+q}=np$$